# How to force update-grub to use UUID?

Tags: boot, grub2, raid

When I run "update-grub", the file "grub.cfg" will contain lines like this.

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu...' {
    ...
    linux /boot/vmlinuz... root=/dev/md124 ...
    ...
}
```

For the line of linux, is it possible to let it use UUID? Like,

```
    linux /boot/vmlinux... root=UUID=xxx
```

Right now, every time after I do update-grub, I have to manually edit the line to use UUID. Otherwise, the boot will fail.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` in `/etc/default/grub` forces GRUB to *not* use UUIDs. If it is present in yours, delete it or comment it out and rerun `update-grub`.

Comment: Confused...mine has the (already commented) line `#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true`.   Is this what you're referring to?  It says "*Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux*".   So I'm confused, because it's commented, and I'm getting `root=/dev/sda1` style output.

Comment: @notfed Even if this line is commented out, there may be other reasons which prevent GRUB from using UUIDs, for example if it is unable for some reason to determine the correct UUID to use.

Comment: And yes, I see that my answer was actually wrong, the line forces GRUB to *not* use UUIDs, otherwise it will use them if possible. I will edit.